# Displaying correct datetime value

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm in the US timezone. I'm trying to parse following dates using C#. What should be the correct value that should be displayed to them user for the following input dates that I'm receiving from another system ?

```
1.2017-10-04T16:24:55.000-04:00 

2.2017-10-04T13:14:35.000+04:00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not use `DateTime`, but use `DateTimeOffset` (or some NodaTime type, as @DiskJunky mentioned). This allows you to parse / store each value with the given time offset.

Your provided texts should work well with default parsing:

```
string test1 = "2017-10-04T16:24:55.000-04:00";
string test2 = "2017-10-04T13:14:35.000+04:00";

DateTimeOffset dateTime;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(test1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date 1: " + dateTime);
}
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(test2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date 2: " + dateTime);
}
```

When the time values are parsed as `DateTimeOffset` you can convert and display them any way you want... for example, get your US adjusted time with `dateTime.ToLocalTime()` or get an easier international exchangeable value with `dateTime.ToUniversalTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of this accurately is to use a library like [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) if you're going to be displaying dates to a user and need to account for time zones. Apart from UTC differences there are also regional DSTs to account for and it's a general nightmare to work with accurately without using a 3rd party library.